# How to mount an online git repo as permanent drive? (linux, ubunutu)

Tags: git, ubuntu, repository, mount, net-use

I want to do what I did on Windows with:

```
net use N:"https://where.the.git.repo.is/" /P:Yes
```

Does anyone know how?

I am new to using linux, but I would like to access this repository as easily as on windows.

Comment: This is more sysadmin/poweruser than programming and better fits there. I have no clue if someone made a userfs implementation for git.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently someone did create a FUSE implementation :

http://www.presslabs.com/gitfs/docs/
  https://github.com/PressLabs/gitfs

I have no idea if this works or not or even why this is useful.

I recommend a more classical use of git though.